# Drupal performance expectations

Tags: 7, performance

Fairly new to Drupal, trying to determine what kind of performance we should expect from a stock Drupal install, with the optional modules (not the barebones option).

We have a fresh dedicated Win 2008 server, 16GB RAM, 8 cores, etc. Hardware shouldn't be an issue.

Latest release of Drupal 7.x. FastCGI. WinCache enabled. MySQL with innoDB.

Load times: 1100-1300ms. Seems crazy high for a FRESH Drupal install (Bartik theme), no custom modules. This is authenticated user, so caching isn't really coming into play.

So, I'm curious, what's the fastest perf we should expect from a fresh Drupal install? **Please list your stack (IIS, Apache, etc), your load speeds (code processing time/database query time).** We're using the devel module (the only extra module) to collect the speed stats.

I don't see how Drupal can be useful without getting down to ~100ms with stock modules, ideally faster. Maybe we have a configuration problem, but this is exactly the same speed we're seeing in the dev environments.

Comment: Try your question over at http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance as this question is more of a discussion and is thus hard to "answer" it.